# Access the value of dropdownlist in gridview edit mode, in DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to perfrom a postback with a Dropdownlist in a Gridview in Edit Mode. I am having problems getting to the value of the drop down. I can not do this in the RowDatabound event.

Postback is not over writing the row, I am stepping into the DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged event where I want to perform some operations, so it hasn't even gotten there. I do have the If Postback in the page load event.

```
  Protected Sub DropDownList7_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows.Item(0), GridViewRow)
    Dim newNumDDL As DropDownList = row.Cells(0).FindControl("DropDownList7")


    Dim newVal As Integer = newNumDDL.SelectedValue
    Dim newKey As String = newNumDDL.SelectedItem.ToString
    Dim newindex As Integer = newNumDDL.SelectedIndex
```

Issue I believe is with the findcontrol I can not find the DDL, keeps coming back nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not use:

```
Dim newNumDDL As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
```